# Finding highest values "zone" in a 2d matrix in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrix

I have a 2d matrix in Python like this (a 10 rows/20 columns list I use to later do an imshow):

```
[[-20.17 -12.88 -20.7  -25.69 -21.69 -34.22 -32.65 -31.74 -36.36 -37.65
  -41.42 -41.14 -44.01 -43.19 -41.85 -39.25 -40.15 -41.31 -39.73 -28.66]
 [ 14.18  53.86  70.03  64.39  72.37  39.95  30.44  28.14  20.77  17.98
   25.74  25.66  27.56  37.61  42.39  42.39  35.79  41.65  41.65  41.84]
 [ 33.71  68.35  69.39  66.7   59.99  40.08  40.08  40.8   26.19  19.82
   19.82  18.07  20.32  19.51  24.77  22.81  21.45  21.45  21.45  23.7 ]
 [103.72  55.11  32.3   29.47  16.53  15.54   9.4    8.11   5.06   5.06
   13.07  13.07  12.99  13.47  13.47  13.47  12.92  12.92  14.27  20.63]
 [ 59.02  18.6   37.53  24.5   13.01  34.35   8.16  13.66  12.57   8.11
    8.11   8.11   8.11   8.11   8.11   5.66   5.66   5.66   5.66   7.41]
 [ 52.69  14.17   7.25  -5.79   3.19  -1.75  -2.43  -3.98  -4.92  -6.68
   -6.68  -6.98  -6.98  -8.89  -8.89  -9.15  -9.15  -9.15  -9.15  -9.15]
 [ 29.24  10.78   0.6   -3.15 -12.55   3.04  -1.68  -1.68  -1.41  -6.15
   -6.15  -6.15 -10.59 -10.59 -10.59 -10.59 -10.59  -9.62 -10.29 -10.29]
 [  6.6    0.11   2.42   0.21  -5.68 -10.84 -10.84 -13.6  -16.12 -14.41
  -15.28 -15.28 -15.28 -18.3   -5.55 -13.16 -13.16 -13.16 -13.16 -14.15]
 [  3.67 -11.69  -6.99 -16.75 -19.31 -20.28 -21.5  -21.5  -34.02 -37.16
  -25.51 -25.51 -26.36 -26.36 -26.36 -26.36 -29.38 -29.38 -29.59 -29.38]
 [ 31.36  -2.87   0.34  -8.06 -12.14 -22.7  -24.39 -25.51 -26.36 -27.37
  -29.38 -31.54 -31.54 -31.54 -32.41 -33.26 -33.26 -15.54 -15.54 -15.54]]
```

I'm trying to find a way to detect the "zone" of this matrix that contains the highest density of high values in it. It means it might not contain the highest single value of the whole list, obviously.

I suppose to do so I should define how big this zone is, so let's say it should be 2x2 (so I want to find what is the 'square' of 2x2 items containing the highest values).

I always think I have a logical solution to do so, but then I always fail following the logic of how it could work!

Anyone has a suggestion I could start from?

Comment: Do you mean what zone has the highest *average value*? Or what determines if a value is "high" or not?

Comment: Treat it like an "image" and convolve it with a kernel of 2x2 (or whatever size) with ones in it, then find the max value.  https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.convolve.html

Comment: @SMcQ I think is the highest average value, possibly also avoiding an average value determined by just one value super high and the others very low...so average value but also more even distribution of this value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know there might be some easier ways to do so, but this is the easiest for me. I've created the following function to perform this task which takes two arguments:

- `arr`: a 2D numpy array.
- `zone_size`: the size of the square zone.

And the function goes like so:

```
def get_heighest_zone(arr, zone_size):
    max_sum = float("-inf")
    row_idx, col_idx = 0, 0
    for row in range(arr.shape[0]-zone_size):
        for col in range(arr.shape[1]-zone_size):
            curr_sum =  np.sum(arr[row:row+zone_size, col:col+zone_size])
            if curr_sum > max_sum:
                row_idx, col_idx = row, col
                max_sum = curr_sum
    return arr[row_idx:row_idx+zone_size, col_idx:col_idx+zone_size]
```

Assuming `arr` is the numpy array posted in your question, applying this function over different `zone_size`s will return these values:

```
>>> get_heighest_zone(arr, 2)
[[70.03 64.39]
 [69.39 66.7 ]]

>>> get_heighest_zone(arr, 3)
[[53.86 70.03 64.39]
 [68.35 69.39 66.7 ]
 [55.11 32.3  29.47]]

>>> get_heighest_zone(arr, 4)
[[ 14.18  53.86  70.03  64.39]
 [ 33.71  68.35  69.39  66.7 ]
 [103.72  55.11  32.3   29.47]
 [ 59.02  18.6   37.53  24.5 ]]
```

If the `zone_size` doesn't have to be square, then you will need to modify a little bit in the code. Also, you should assert that `zone_size` is less than the array size.

Hopefully, this is what you was looking for!

Comment: interesting...it works a bit like I had it my head...I'm going to test it and will report back!

Comment: I also need to modify it slightly to return me the zone "coordinates" in the x/y grid and not just the values, will work on it!

Comment: You can use `row_idx` and `col_idx` to do so.

Comment: Actually that is exactly what I was looking for, very neat concept for it thanks a lot, will expand it now to consider different shaped zones!

Comment: Glad I could help